# Why do I get a syntax error on a record type definition in Delphi scripting?

Tags: scripting, syntax-error, record, pascalscript, proteus-erp

I tried to make a custom record type in order to store information of a product and call it in functions and procedures when needed. The code is written in a script compiler of a Delphi based ERP program. The problem I'm facing is that I get a syntax error on the record type definition when I execute the script.
I searched the internet for an hour or so, but wasn't able to find a solution. My script is as next:

```
Unit Paneelwand;

interface

Uses System, Classes, DB, SysUtils, Graphics, Types;

type 
TPanel = record
            Ref, PType : string;
            Width, Heigth, Thickness, PriceSheets, PriceBitum, PriceHardboard, PricePermmFrameWidth, PricePermmFrameHeigth : float;
        end;

implementation
//rest of the code
```

The syntax Error is on line 6 "TPanel = record". I can't find what I did wrong. Please, help?

By the way: the script is saved as a .psc file and referenced to in another script with its filename as a reference in the uses section. This works fine with other scripts I wrote. I also never had to add a unit line as the scripts are called by the file names.
I updated the script, by deleting the part that is not part of the problem and added the changes that were suggested below by the great people that try to help me. However, the error remains on the same line --> 'TPanel = record;'.

Comment: type is a [reserved word](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements_(Delphi)), you will have to use an other name,

Comment: ...or prefix the reserved word with an ampersand character (`&type`).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Ha, forgot about that one :)

Comment: You also have a stray `if ` on the sixth line from the end, and a strangely empty conditional on the fourth line from the end. And an unmatched `[` and an unterminated string literal on line 8 from the end. And an erroneous `]` at the end of that line.

Comment: The error is pretty clear `E2029 Identifier expected but 'TYPE' found`.  Compiler errors and warnings are there to help you out - it really helps to read what they say and to try to understand what they mean.  When posting a question, it really helps to include the exact error text so that people don't have to resort to trying to reproduce your code and compile it to see what the error is.  Also, you're naming a record `TPanel`, which steps on the VCL and FMX `TPanel` components, so the lesson today is - choose unique identifiers for your type and variable names.

Comment: @whosrdaddy; You are right of course and I just changed it, however, the syntax error I get is one line higher on 'TPanel = record' and after I changed Type into PType the error remains.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand; You're right aswell. I knew about that one and as wasn't done with writing the code when tested it. Sorry I posted that part. However the error is on the line TPanel = record. I also changed the code to '''type test : string;''' and that gave an error on the line 'test : string;'.

Comment: @J...; Thank you for your comment. I know that it's necessary to post the error, which I did. It is a syntax error and that's all it sais. If I would have gotten the error you described, I wouldn't have posted this question. As I stated in other comments, the error apears on the line before the declaration of Type. The error is on the line with 'TPanel = record'. If I change the entire code to just 'type test: string;' I get the same syntax error on the line test : string;'. Maybe declarations of custom types are not allowed in the script compiler ?

Comment: @M.devries: The beginning of the file is also incorrect. First, you are missing the `unit` line. Second, `interface` should precede the `uses` list of the interface section.

Comment: @M.devries Sorry, you tagged this Delphi.  I missed that this is some delphi-like scripting language.  I don't know what language that is or what its rules are.  What ERP program is this?  That is the tag you should be using.

Comment: @Areas Rejbrand; Thanks for your comment. I changed what you suggested and updated the question with that syntax. However, I did put the uses section between brackets. Otherwise, I get a syntax error on the uses section. Just for testing of course. I also added some extra information about how the scripts are used to the question.

Comment: @J...; Thanks for taking your efforts anyway :). The ERP program is most likely not very known on this forum as it is a very specific one with only just over a hundred clients or so. Its called Proteus and made for the woodworking business in the Netherlands and Belgium.

Comment: @M.devries Is it using PascalScript?  It seems the most likely case.

Comment: You have a lot of syntax errors. e.g. `Unit Paneelwand` without the ending `;` also `TPanel = record;` the ending `;` is incorrect. `PType := string` instead of `PType : string` and so on...

Comment: @kobik those errors were just edited into the question about 45 minutes ago...

Comment: @Kobik; I'm very sorry about that. Like J.. stated that has been edited 45min. ago indeed. I have been testing with all kind of syntaxes and overlooked those things when I pasted the code when editing in the question. I've cleaned the code again, but the error remains.

Comment: @ J...; You might be right. The syntax of Delphi and Pascal are very similar I guess. Does this mean that the declaration of custom types is not possible in pascal scripting? :(.

Comment: @M.devries I don't know.  I've never used Pascalscript.  I've voted to reopen this question.  My close vote was because this seemed to be a simple typo, which it would be in Delphi.  Given that it is Pascalscript, there may be an issue here.  It may also be a bug in Proteus.

Comment: @J...; Okay I understand, thank you for reopening the issue. I'll also contact the Proteus support to see if they'll come up with something. Unfortunately, experience tells me that the response to this type of questions is limited or takes a very long time (too complicated for the helpdesk and limited time on development department). I'll post the answer here if they'll give one. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 3):

"Type" is reserved word. try other word

Comment: Thank you David. You are right of course and I just changed it, however, the syntax error I get is one line higher on 'TPanel = record' and after I changed Type into PType the error remains.

Comment: {Uses System, Classes, DB, SysUtils, Graphics, Types;} - remove the brackets.

Comment: Thank you for your comment David. I placed the brackets because I got another error on that line. I've resolved the issue with that line, but the error with the declaration of the record type remains. I guess it is because of it is scripting. I've asked the ERP software producer and I'm waiting for their answer. I'm afraid that what I want isn't possible.